# Statistics change after TIFF import?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-conversion

Statistics (mean, min, max) change quite a lot after importing a .TIF grid file (DEM) into GRASS. According to GDAL queries in QGIS, the TIF has the following properties:

```
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2.2400000095367
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.05137734831008
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-3.5300002098083
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.43984890430363
```

After import in GRASS, with region set according to this grid (extent & cellsize), GRASS lists the properties as follows:

```
...
minimum: -4.21
maximum: 2.99
...
mean: 0.0451878
standard deviation: 0.435221
```

Especially the difference in the 'mean' worries me a bit.  I checked extent and cell size, they are identical.

Does anybody have any idea why the results (especially the 'mean') are different?

I'm new to this forum, and pretty much a beginner with GRASS (7.0.0beta3 installed atm).

Comment: Be sure to have the http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region set properly to the raster map.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I did set the computational region in GRASS according to the properties of the imported grid and verified this step, before I calculated the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the statistics are calculated through sampling. This could cause the differences.
Try to use gdalinfo with the -stat option to calculate image statistics and see if there are differences

Comment: thanks for the tip. I recalculated statistics for the original TIF using gdalinfo -stats, but the numbers do not change unfortunately. So the change in statistics after import into GRASS remains. Do you, or anybody else, have any suggestion what else could explain the difference?

Comment: For verification, I just loaded the original TIF in ArcView and (re)calculated the statistics. They proved to be identical to GRASS numbers. So I think you are on the right track with your suggestion. I am guessing that gdalinfo (with or without -stats) somehow makes a mistake in calculating statistics. Maybe because of the technique it uses for this (sampling).

Comment: Note: gdalinfo -mm  Force computation of the actual min/max values for each band in the dataset (rather than using heuristics)